# jquery return value of a non-existing id or class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if an object has same id on DOM, because i am trying to create a modal window library,

the problem is in browsers console when i write

```
$("#anonexistingid");
```

it returns `[]`

but in my code

```
if($("#"+id)!==[]){
        return;
    }
```

just does not work. What is the proper way of defining an empty array?(Because i think [] means empty array, maybe not i am not sure :D)

Comment: In any case, two objects are only equal if they are identical (the same). Even `[] == []` returns `false`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JQuery always returns an object. you can check it's length to see if it's empty or not:

```
if($("#"+id).length !== 0){

}
```

Comment: @kobe: Yes but it is more explicit which can be easier to understand. ( `> 0` would be even better imo.)

Answer (score 4):

[] is an empty array. To test if empty, try:

```
if($("#"+id).length) { 
     //Element is found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this . it returns true if object is empty , else returns false

```
 jQuery.isEmptyObject({}) // true
 jQuery.isEmptyObject({ foo: "bar" }) // false
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`size()` method](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

```
   if($("#"+id).size() > 0){
        return;
    }
```

This method returns the number of matched elements by `$`.

Hope this helps. Cheers